# Is The DAO voting right proportional to the account tokens balance?

Tags: tokens, the-dao, balances, voting

Will I have more power on decisions if my token balance is high, or do I always have one vote whatever my balance is?

Comment: If you had one vote per address, people would just create thousands of addresses with one token each. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have one vote per account, but your one vote has the weighting of your account's token balance. And as `@Nick Johnson` commented below, this is functionally equivalent to having one vote per token.

- If you vote Yea, the balance of your token account is added to the Yea accumulator.
- If you vote Nay, the balance of your token account is added to the Nay accumulator.

From [EtherScan - The DAO - Contract Source](http://etherscan.io/address/0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413#code) (or the [Solidity realtime compiler and runtime view](https://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity/?#gist=817513bd947126ac9e80eefda9f69ca0&version=soljson-v0.3.1-2016-04-12-3ad5e82.js&optimize=true)):

```
function vote(
    uint _proposalID,
    bool _supportsProposal
) onlyTokenholders noEther returns (uint _voteID) {

    Proposal p = proposals[_proposalID];
    if (p.votedYes[msg.sender]
        || p.votedNo[msg.sender]
        || now >= p.votingDeadline) {

        throw;
    }

    if (_supportsProposal) {
        p.yea += balances[msg.sender];
        p.votedYes[msg.sender] = true;
    } else {
        p.nay += balances[msg.sender];
        p.votedNo[msg.sender] = true;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: ...which is functionally equivalent to having one vote per token.